# s3cmd : copy file from encrypted buckets in s3 to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I want to download a file from an encypted bucket in s3. The bucket is encrypted using AES256. I am using the following command

```
s3cmd --access_key=<access_key> --secret_key=<secret_key> get <s3_key_location> <target_loc>.
```

I read the [s3 usage](http://s3tools.org/usage). It did not help much.

How do I specify the option that I want to download the file after decryption from s3?

Also since the bucket is encrypted, this command creates a dummy file with the same name as the key present in the s3 location having a size 0 in the target location.

One important thing to note here is that I am using boto to run the `s3cmd` commands.

**s3cmd version 1.5.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So along with this optional parameter `--server-side-encryption` you have to give the encryption paraphrase while configuring the s3cmd.

Unfortunately , I did not find any parameter in the s3cmd command which can override the value specified in the encryption paraphrase. There are a couple of ways with which you can configure the encryption paraphase :

1.using the `s3cmd --configure` option

2.Modifying the `.s3cfg` config file present in the home directory.

I was looking for a parameter which can override the value given in the config file.

Example : If the access key in the file is A and while running the s3cmd I specify `--access_key B`. The value A will not be used for the s3cmd for that command execution , however the value A will always be used when we are not specifying the access key. So If there is any parameter for encryption paraphase also , please post that here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use aws command line? I guess it has better support with encrypted s3 bucket.

e.g. `aws s3 cp <s3_path> <local_path>`

https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: I am executing this command via a python code. I have a list of files to be copied, so cannot use CLI.

Comment: @psycho: The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is an app just like `s3cmd`, so if you can use that, then you can also use the CLI. If you wish to incorporate commands within your Python code, use `boto`.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 objects encrypted with *server side encryption* are automatically decrypted when they are retrieved. The encryption affects how the data is *stored on disk* but you will never *see* encrypted objects.

Therefore, just download the file as normal.

By the way, these days it is preferable to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

If you wish to download via Python, use the `boto` function: [`get_contents_to_file()`](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.get_contents_to_file)